# Eyes follow me, but i don't want them to

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, 3d-view, import

I imported a .vrm file into blender, and for some reason, the eyes follow me, not the camera, ME, in the viewport. I actually have a few .vrm files that do this. Is there a setting where i can turn that off? i'm using 2.79.

picture: https://i.imgur.com/xPiAPRh.gifv

there are no constraints, no modifiers, nothing that i can find.

Comment: Sounds like your computer needs an exorcism. Could you be more specific about as to how the eyes move? Is it related to the user camera? Is a constrained involved? (Maybe post an image or gif)

Comment: i expected more serious replies. i thought i was pretty clear, but i guess i'll edit my question to include a visual example...

Answer (score 1):

Ohhh, that was clever!

I'm almost 99% sure it's just a trick of topology.
They eyes are sunken so they appear to rotate in the opposite direction as the observer (you!).

It's the exact same illusion as this mask:
[image]

The fact that your viewport has no or little shading reinforces the illusion.

Can you go into edit mode confirm that the eyes are sunken and when you make them flush with the face, the creepy effect stops?

If yes, then rest assured, your computer is NOT haunted.

Comment: they were sunken in, but i moved them up on my edit, and they still slightly do the same thing. also, quite a view .vrm files i have DON'T do that